# Upgrading PS4 Minecraft from disc to online

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, ps4

Our Minecraft disc is now damaged and we want to purchase the online version. Will we still be able to access the saved worlds we had when we used the disc?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, saved data is interchangeable between Physical and Digital versions of Minecraft Bedrock.

The only difference is that you will loose access to Minecraft Legacy Console Edition. Access to MCLCE is only available on Physical copies and Digital purchases before December 9, 2019.